# Pointer to member-function for SDL audio callback?

Tags: c++, pointers, callback, sdl, member

I'm using SDL 1.2.15 to play audio from libav (ffmpeg) like in this example [here](http://dranger.com/ffmpeg/tutorial03.html).

I have declared a class for playing the sound.  But now I have to store a pointer for the callback function in the `SDL_AudioSpec::callback` (in the example `wanted_spec.callback`).  But my callback is a member of my class.

The callback pointer in SDL is:

```
void (SDLCALL *callback)(void *userdata, Uint8 *stream, int len);
```

where `SDLCALL` is `__cdecl`.

How can I store a pointer of a member-function in my `wanted_spec_.callback`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to use a non-static member function to handle the callbacks you will need to provide a forwarding function and set `userdata` to the pointer to the target object.

```
struct CallbackObject
{
    void onCallback(Uint8 *stream, int len)
    {
        // ....
    }

    static void forwardCallback(void *userdata, Uint8 *stream, int len)
    {
        static_cast<CallbackObject*>(userdata)->onCallback(stream, len);
    }
};



SDL_AudioSpec audio;
CallbackObject callbackObject;

audio.callback = CallbackObject::forwardCallback;
audio.userdata = &callbackObject;
```

Comment: very smart! nice solution.